# TypeError unsupported operand type(s)

Tags: python, python-2.7, math

```
from math import *

a = input("A= ")
b = input("B= ")
c = input("C= ")

d = b*b-(4*a*c)

print "The discriminent is: %s!" %d
if d >= 0:
    x1 = (0-b+sqrt(d))/2*a
    x2 = (0-b-sqrt(d))/2*a
    print "First answer is: %s!" %x1
    print "Second answer is: %s!" %x2
else:
    print "X can't be resolved!"
```

Was working completely fine until I tried these parameters.

```
A= 0,5
B= -2
C= 2
```

Then it printed out this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Mathias/Documents/Projects/Skole/project/test/Math.py", line 9, in <module>
    d = b*b-(4*a*c)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'tuple'
```

I can't seem to figure out how to solve this, can someone help me?

Comment: try again, but replace `0,5`by `0.5`

Answer (score 2):

Python uses the period `.` to indicate the decimal point, **not** the comma `,`; your input should be `0.5`.

This would have given you an error earlier had you used the recommended:

```
a = float(raw_input("A= "))
```

rather than `input` (which is equivalent to `eval(raw_input())` and has **interpreted `0,5` as a two-tuple `(0, 5)`**):

```
>>> eval("0,5")
(0, 5)
>>> float("0,5")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    float("0,5")
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 0,5
```

Per [the documentation for `input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input):

> Consider using the `raw_input()` function for general input from users.

Comment: That "Consider using the raw_input() function" should really read "**Always** use raw_input() unless you know exactly what you're doing"...

Comment: @l4mpi:... or if you are using Python 3  (OP must be using Python 2 because of the `print` statements)

Comment: @l4mpi I agree, but that's the quote as it stands